# Why are alias names defined in .bashrc file are not working as expected?

Tags: alias, bashrc

I have give alias names in .bashrc file like below. But the alias names are not working. why?

```
alias c='clear'
alias l='ls -lt'
alias h='history'
alias d='ls -lt |grep "^d"'

export ORACLE_HOME=/ora11gr2/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db2
export ORACLE_LIB=/ora11gr2/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db2/lib
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/vac/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin:.    
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:.
```

Comment: Are you saying you get the environement variables but not the aliases, or you get none of it?

Comment: May be a separate issue, but you wipe out your PATH. You should reference your old PATH in any setting, e.g. `export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/vac/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin:.` `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/lib`

Comment: Have you tried restarting the shell session?

Answer (score 40):

Did you source your `.bashrc` file after you changed it?  Try:

```
. ~/.bashrc
```

Then your shell should see the changes.  Alternatively, you can terminate and restart your shell.

p.s.

When you run from a script, load this first [ref](https://www.thegeekdiary.com/how-to-make-alias-command-work-in-bash-script-or-bashrc-file/)

```
shopt -s expand_aliases
```

Comment: This solved my problem! Before that, I even tried to log out and in again through the SSH, but nothing happened. The alias was still not available. Looks like I have to do this every time I do the SSH! Do you know why is this happening?

Comment: I don't recommend re-running `.bashrc`. It can cause some duplicate and swollen values. Why not exit and start a new shell? It will load the updated `.bashrc` file.

Comment: @AlikElzin-kilaka, thats what Vladimir tried but it was not working.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case any macOS users come looking for this answer, I tried this on my MacBook and even restarting the Terminal would not load the new alias definitions.

The only way I could get it to work was to `source ~/.bashrc` every time.

Then I tried moving my alias definitions to `~/.bash_profile` and *this* is what did the trick.

Comment: As a new mac user who was getting confused - thank you!

Answer (score 3):

This may happen because your PATH has not been set correctly to use all alias referenced binaries' absoulte path. i.e `ls` exists under `/bin/ls`.

Can you give a try using

```
export PATH=$PATH:$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/vac/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin:.
```

or somthing like

```
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/vac/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin:/bin:/sbin/:/usr/sbin
```

If not, then use `which` to find the path directory for individual alias ref binaries (which history).

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you are trying to define your aliases in your `.bashrc` that are already global.

Usually your aliases in `.bashrc` are defined before the `/etc/bashrc` call.
Try to define them  **after**.

Here an example of your `.bashrc`:

```
# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# User specific aliases and functions
alias c='clear'
alias l='ls -lt'
alias h='history'
alias d='ls -lt |grep "^d"'

export ORACLE_HOME=/ora11gr2/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db2
export ORACLE_LIB=/ora11gr2/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/db2/lib
export PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/bin:/usr/vac/bin:/usr/vacpp/bin:.    
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:.
```

Comment: Terrific answer! I'm seeing this consistently in AWS Linux AMI's

Answer (score 1):

Questions to ask yourself are:

- Is the ~/.bashrc already executed in your shell. It only runs when the shell is started.
  If you open a new shell (execute `bash`) it should be.
  With `alias` you should see all your aliases printed.
- Second thing to ask: are the programs in your aliases available. At least h (alias history) should
  definitely work, because it is builtin.

Answer (score 1):

Change the user's shell from `/bin/sh` to `/bin/bash`. This is all that needs to be done to make the `.bashrc` aliases and such work.

Answer (score 1):

I had a bunch of stuff in my `~/.zshrc` and it was unclear which was overwriting `ls` as `ls -G`. Putting `alias ls='exa'` at the very bottom helped.

Answer (score 0):

I'm embarrassed to type this but the reason aliases weren't working for me is because I had a space in between:

`alias c = 'clear'`

With `alias c='clear'` it works.

Answer (score 0):

***Note**: Deal with `~/.bashrc` or `~/.zshrc` according to the shell you use.*

---

1. Make sure first what shell do use the command below will let you know:

   ```bash
   $ echo "$SHELL"
   ```
2. Why do you have to know? Because editing the `~/.bashrc` while you use Zsh and even re-sourcing or logging out will give no benefit since you configure a file for shell ur not currently using and that was the case with me.

**Commands**: If you use Zsh ~> `nano /.zshrc`. If you use Bash ~> `nano /.bashrc` and so on.