# bashrc alias ls not working

Tags: bash, terminal, shell

I'm trying to modify the ls command with an alias in my .bashrc file, and I'm getting some strange errors.

.bashrc file

```
export http_proxy="Some URL"  
export https_proxy=$http_proxy 

alias ls='ls --color'
```

Then, when I try `ls`, the output is

```
's: unrecognized option '--color
Try 'ls --help' for more information.
```

If I remove the alias from my .bashrc and run `ls --color`, I see the expected result.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, but help would be appreciated. Each time I make a change, I do restart the terminal to ensure the .bashrc is reloaded. OS is Ubuntu 14.04.

Some things that might be relevant

- The empty line in my .bashrc causes `: command not found` to be displayed to the terminal when I open up a new one.
- If I run `alias ls='ls --color'` in the terminal, the alias works correctly.
- Technically, I am on Windows, using Cygwin to SSH onto this Ubuntu VM.

Related questions
[why alias names defined in .bashrc file are not working?](https://superuser.com/questions/441982/why-alias-names-defined-in-bashrc-file-are-not-working)
http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/bashrc-aliases-don't-work-267885/
[Alias not working in Debian](https://superuser.com/questions/488601/alias-not-working-in-debian)
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44616/why-is-vim-creating-files-with-dos-line-endings

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. I noticed when I opened my .bashrc in vim, there was a little `[dos]` in the bottom.

I then  ran `dos2unix .bashrc` to convert it to Unix file endings and the problem is fixed.

Upon further reading, it seems like Cygwin may have had something to do with the dos line endings. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/44616/why-is-vim-creating-files-with-dos-line-endings.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to use double quotes for that.  Double quotes preserve the complete meaning of what you type, while single does not.  [Read this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash) for more info.

So your code should look like this

```
alias ls="ls --color"
```

Comment: Switched to double quotes as you suggested, and no change to the error message.

Comment: Is that your entire .bashrc file? if you could show us more we might be able to spot the problem.

Comment: That's the entire .bashrc.

Comment: Ok.  I'm glad you got it figured out.